# How do I skip items when tabbing without using tabindex?

Tags: javascript, focus, tab-ordering

Is there a good way, in a javascript onfocus() handler, to trampoline the focus to the next item in the tab order, without having to manually enter the ID of the item that should be next?

I built an HTML date picker in Django/jQuery.  It's a line edit followed by a calendar icon that pops up a calendar.  I want to be able to tab from the line edit to the next input, skipping the link for the calendar icon.  I mean for it to be a generalized widget, so I can't hardcode the id of whatever is next and call .focus().  I know I could set tabindex attributes on everything, but that's more manual than I'd like.  Also, iirc, that wouldn't prevent it from taking the focus, it would just put it at the end of the tab order.

Answer (score 28):

Set tabindex = "-1" for that control and browser will skip that control from tabbing.

Comment: This works, but it's not valid.  Validators are cranky.  Is there a simple way to be valid?  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex. "This value must be a number between 0 and 32767."

Comment: Seems to work on FF10 and IE9 at least. @dfrakow, looks like this is a defacto standard. Validation be damned...

Comment: I like this solution :)

Comment: Just to add to mlissner's comment, this also works great on Chrome and Safari!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
$("#your-calendar-icon").focus(function() {
  $(this).trigger("blur");
);
```

Comment: This doesn't skip focus, it resets it so that when tab is next pressed it will select the first element on the page

Answer (score 2):

or:

```
$("#your-calendar-icon").focus(function() {
    $(somethingElse).trigger("focus");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this resources:

- [Getting, setting, and removing tabindex values with JavaScript](http://fluidproject.org/blog/2008/01/09/getting-setting-and-removing-tabindex-values-with-javascript/)
- [jQuery Tabindex Plugin](http://fluidproject.org/blog/2008/01/11/jquery-tabindex-plugin/)

Comment: those links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a div around the calendar icon instead of a link.  Then attach your calendar events to the div.  By default, the div won't be a tab stop.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be the input after the calendar then why not:

```
$('#your-calendar-icon').focus( function() {
  $(this).next('input').focus();
} );
```

Personally, I'd say that if it's going to be a plugin you should just make the next element a configuration option that has a default, and specify the default in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As @thetacom says, you can just use another type of element, one that doesn't receive focus. In case you still want to keep some of the <kbd>tab</kbd> functionality, you can try [SkipOnTab](https://joelpurra.com/projects/skipontab/).

> [SkipOnTab](https://joelpurra.com/projects/skipontab/): A jQuery plugin to exempt selected form fields from the forward tab order.

Just add `data-skip-on-tab="true"` to the date picker icon (or other elements/containers) you want to skip. You can still click to activate the date picker or go back using <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> and use the enter key.

See [the simple demo](https://joelpurra.com/projects/skipontab/docs/example/demo.html) and [the business case demo](https://joelpurra.com/projects/skipontab/docs/example/skip-some-fields-in-order-form.html).