# How to navigating only by positive tabindex

Tags: html, css, dom, tabindex

I have 4 links with `tabindex` from 1 to 4. When I load the page and press `tab` I jump to the first link. Press tab else - jump to the second and so on...

But when I press tab after fourth link - I jump to the other links that don't have tabindex. So when I

How can I cycling navigating with this 4 links (navigating only by positive tabindex) i.e. when I'm on the link with tabindex = 4 and pressing a tab - I'm jumping to the link with tabindex = 1, not to the other links?

I'm wondering how to do that without javaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate over HTML elements when pressing Tab key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935787/how-to-rotate-over-html-elements-when-pressing-tab-key)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate tabindex through html form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738008/rotate-tabindex-through-html-form)

Comment: you don't need tab index to be able to tab - tab index lets you prioritise elements and the order you will tab through them. It does not mean that other elements on the page will be ignored.

Comment: @Dhunt At first, I really need to prioritise them, so I need `tabindex`. And I also need to ignore other links in order to navigating only by this 4 links cyclically

Comment: I haven't tried this out but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412070/how-do-i-skip-items-when-tabbing-without-using-tabindex . Watch you don't cause other issues where if you have a form on the page you are ignoring the form elements as a lot of people will tab through the form to fill it in.

Comment: @Dhunt Thanks. Looks like it's impossible without JavaScript :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make other tabs not able to enter on the tabindex focus, give them a value of -1. This make them not focusable when you click the tab key.

Comment: If/when you do this, do not forget about users that depend entirely on keyboard navigation.